# count(*) return less than actual rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a query

`SELECT count(*) FROM (subquery) tf`

and it returns 208 rows. But if I write

`SELECT * FROM (subquery) tf`

I get 211 rows. There is no duplicate rows. Have you ever faced this problem?

Comment: Only when the first query uses an index-only scan and the index is corrupted.